# How to tell if a software was installed on the system or not?

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, security

Someone installed a software on a system using DHCP IP. We would like to audit the systems but How to trace if the software was installed on the particular system or not after it has been uninstalled? Or after the suspicious user tried to delete all traces of that software? Any concrete methods to trace which cannot be manipulated ? -WINDOWS
(note- I know registry will have some details but that can also be manipulated)

Answer (score 0):

> How to trace if the software was installed on the particular system or not after it has
> been uninstalled?

Not at all. Period.

Ok, if the software is written badly (depending on the software) or there are requirements of the software that result in traces being left behind, you can go by those. I.e. a software not cleaning up the registry keys it creates. But this is not a general mechanism.

> Or after the suspicious user tried to delete all traces of that software?

Basically: We have users who are idiots? Because if the user KNOWS what he is doing, he is doing it, not trying. If he is trying, you are back to the first answer.

> Any concrete methods to trace which cannot be manipulated ?**

Absolutely. Not. There is NO method that can not be manipulated. Ask all the companies making copy protection for the last 30 years or so.

Comment: Could you suggest some methods anyway, if not concrete then most dependable way?

Comment: Nope. Literally. I mean, there is not a lot more than looking at possible leftovers in the file system and registry and all of them are TOTALLY DEPENDENT ON THE SOFTWARE. IITC there is some stuff to get differentials (some software, used to make installers). You can install a piece of software, uninstall it, use a differential between original and the end status and see whether anything sensible has changed. But generally: it depends on the exact software.